# Formatting DateTime - ignore culture

Tags: c#

I need to format a date to the following format:

`M-d-yyyy`

I tried using:

`string.Format("{0:M-d-yyyy}", DateTime.Now)`

But the output string will depend on the CurrentCulture on the computer where it's run, so sometimes the output might be `07/09/2014` or `07.09.2014` instead of `09-07-2014`.

How can I easily prevent it from converting it based on the culture and treating it as a literal string?

Comment: What culture would generate dots and slashes instead of bars?

Comment: @CommuSoft, German culture generates dots for example. I believe it is Portuguese culture that uses slashes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as the culture or provider argument.

```
String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:M-d-yyyy}", DateTime.Now)
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as an `IFormatProvider` parameter:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("M-d-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the culture of your program with this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;`
```

You can also use a specific culture if you want (I think `en-US` is the one you need)

Comment: That solves the problem. But is not always the intended effect: say you only want to format dates, not the names of the week? Or you want to typeset integers in the old way

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("d", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

or apply other formatting specs as detailed in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Pertinent to your case it could be written as:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("M-d-yyyy", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

Regards,

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `.ToString()` method on the `DateTime` object to format it however you'd like.  Your code would look something like this:

`DateTime.Now.ToString("M-d-yyyy");`

More info on formatting date times can be found on the MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

you can try
date.ToString("MM/dd/yy", yyyymmddFormat);

or
try whats in this link
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/af4f5a1e-f81d-47fe-981d-818e785b8847/convert-string-to-datetime-object

you can force the string into a standard format if you like